# Conditional Expectation and Conditional Variance of die

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I've been doing this but not getting this answer. Can anyone guide me to right answer?

Let X be the number obtained when one true die is tossed. Let T be the sum of numbers obtained when X true dice are then thrown. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[T]$ and $Var[T]$.

Right answers are:

$$\mathbb{E}[T] = \frac{49}{4}$$
$$Var[T] = \frac{735}{16}$$

Comment: What have you tried? Since $T$ depends on $X$, problems like these are typically solved with the law of total expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}[T] = \sum_{x =1}^{6} \mathbb{E}[T|X=x] \mathbb{P}[X = x].$$

Comment: Like @Siron I'd break it into cases (Siron is absolutely correct, but sort of takes a shortcut)